# a recursive query in the mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, recursion

Prompt how to implement a recursive problem to Mysql:

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE t_info(id INT PRIMARY KEY, parent_id INT, info VARCHAR(32));
```

Need to get info by id of ID row and info of parent of ID and info of parent of parent of ID etc until the first parent.

How to do it in one SQL query?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy the dupe ref is getting children. Here parents are sought

Comment: With the reverse join can we not get parents?

Comment: Lots of helpful information here: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @KannanKandasamy if you have the op schema (ref to parent) and you can find a dupe target that solves it, sure, ping me, will close it

Comment: @hogan that gets children. Op wants parents on up

Comment: @Drew -- there is no difference

Comment: @Hogan except that they are going in a different direction and the question is different

Comment: @drew you are joining to the parent or you are joining to the child -- there is no "direction" in relational databases.... except when they go south :D

Comment: @Hogan the answer, call it the one with 46 votes, finds Electronics on down to walkie-talkies. It won't go up to find higher level categories above Electronics. So it is not a solution. Cheers

Comment: @Drew -- take that solution and replace every instance of parent with child and child with parent and then it will go up. Please don't be so unaware of data structures this is not obvious.

Comment: When you dupe close point out the discrepancy to the op. Data is my thing so I am quite aware of data structures.